# Shape Detection API: "DOMException: Source would taint origin"

Tags: javascript

I am playing with Shape Detection API (https://github.com/WICG/shape-detection-api), basing on this examples: https://wicg.github.io/shape-detection-api/#examples

I am trying to get the simplest one to work:

```
let faceDetector = new FaceDetector({fastMode: true, maxDetectedFaces: 1});
// Assuming |theImage| is e.g. a <img> content, or a Blob.

faceDetector.detect(theImage)
.then(detectedFaces => {
  for (const face of detectedFaces) {
    console.log(' Face @ (${face.boundingBox.x}, ${face.boundingBox.y}),' +
    ' size ${face.boundingBox.width}x${face.boundingBox.height}');
  }
}).catch(() => {
  console.error("Face Detection failed, boo.");
})
```

However, I am getting error:

```
VM153:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Source would taint origin.
```

Image variable with I am using is one of images from stackoverflow:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/619aaf27f793d8ffdbc879c74884c0cc?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="32" height="32" id="testimg">
```

My browser is Google Chrome Canary 61.0.3128.0, with the Experimental Web Features enabled.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi, Michal! I'm having the same issue. Could you please tell me how did you manage to fix this in the end?

Comment: Hey Alex. I never came back to the issue. Isn't any of the answers below helpful?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is here:
https://wicg.github.io/shape-detection-api/#image-sources-for-detection

> "If any ImageBitmapSource have an effective script origin (HTML Standard §concept-origin) which is not the same as the Document’s effective script origin, then reject the Promise with a new DOMException whose name is SecurityError."

Do not miss wrap you code if you are using loading image via HTML tag

```
window.onload = () => {
    // TODO: put you code here 
};
```

or via Image constructor

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = 'faces.jpg'
image.onload = () => {
    // TODO: put your code here
}
```

[Code example](https://github.com/CornCodeCorp/courses/blob/master/src/post_10/index.html)

Comment: "Do not miss wrap you code if you are using loading image via HTML tag" what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that the image's source origin should be the same as the location where you are gonna execute the script