# Source would taint origin

Tags: javascript

Why does following code throw “Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'detect' on 'BarcodeDetector': Source would taint origin.” when opening file in browser (file:///Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/index.html)?

Might relate to following mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507125/shape-detection-api-domexception-source-would-taint-origin) question… if so, how can one work around limitation?

> If any ImageBitmapSource have an effective script origin (origin) which is not the same as the Document’s effective script origin, then reject the Promise with a new DOMException whose name is SecurityError.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BarcodeDetector</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>See “Console” tab of dev tools…</h1>
    <img id="qr" src="https://tails.boum.org/donate/bitcoin-bc1qjg53lww9jrm506dj0g0szmk4pxt6f55x8dncuv.png" />
     <script>
      const test = async (qr) => {
        const barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector({ formats: ["qr_code"] })
        const detectedBarcodes = await barcodeDetector.detect(qr)
        detectedBarcodes.forEach((detectedBarcode) => {
          console.log(detectedBarcode.rawValue)
        })
        // Expected console.log output => bitcoin:bc1qjg53lww9jrm506dj0g0szmk4pxt6f55x8dncuv
      }

      const qr = document.getElementById("qr")

      qr.addEventListener('load', () => {
        test(qr)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you loading `BarcodeDetector` in your source code as well?

Comment: As you haven't shared the code behind `BarcodeDetector`, it's impossible to provide help

Comment: [BarcodeDetector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BarcodeDetector) is natively supported on Chromium-based browsers on macOS (among other implementations).

Comment: Oh, I see, didn't know that! Thanks for clarify. :)

Comment: Not sure who voted to close this question, but guys… please chill.

Comment: This is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507125/shape-detection-api-domexception-source-would-taint-origin) but might be similar to your issue, could you check?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @node_modules. Had stumbled upon that question, but unfortunately didn’t help.

Comment: Looks like the issue here is the same as with a "tainted canvas" - because you are loading the image from a different origin, access to the actual image content is denied. So unless you can get the source to CORS-enable that image, there is little other option than to use an image proxy, so that your script would be loading the image from the _same_ origin then.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @CBroe… normal that I get same error when file is loaded locally (`<img id="qr" src="bitcoin-bc1qjg53lww9jrm506dj0g0szmk4pxt6f55x8dncuv.png" />`)?

Comment: _"when opening file in browser (file:///Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/index.html)"_ - in that case, you do not have a "real" origin. This is the same as AJAX/fetch requests behave - even if the request is only to a relative URL, it won't work when the page is loaded via the `filr:///` protocol. You _need to_ use HTTP(S).